# How to display only two products as Cross Sell products in cart page Magento 2.3.2?

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.2, cross-sells

How to show only 2 products as corss sells in the cart view page, irrespective of the product that gets added to cart.

Thanks.

Comment: please check this link  https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/change-crosssell-product-limit-in-magento-2/ . I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have create the cart page cross sell product only two products showing.

> Mag/Cool/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mag_Cool',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Mag/Cool/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" type="Mag\Cool\Block\Cart\Crosssell" />
</config>
```

> Mag/Cool/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mag_Cool" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
     </module>
</config>
```

> Mag/Cool/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php

```
<?php

namespace Mag\Cool\Block\Cart;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock as StockHelper;

class Crosssell extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkFactory $productLinkFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\RelatedProducts $itemRelationsList,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $checkoutSession,
            $productVisibility,
            $productLinkFactory,
            $itemRelationsList,
            $stockHelper,
            $data
        );

        $this->_maxItemCount = 2; // set your product limit here
    }
}
```

This code is working fine And check the video [click here](https://www.loom.com/share/652f07a5d2314e1d88259599892e1b94)

Comment: Your di.xml should be in etc/ not in etc/frontend/